# Gradle-built project structure

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I see a lot of examples of Gradle-built Java/Groovy projects that have the following structure:

```
some-app/
    src/
        main/
        test/
    docs/
    README.md
    build.gradle
    gradlew
    gradlew.bat
    settings.gradle
    gradle.properties
    gradle/
        *.gradle
```

I understand that **build.gradle** is the main buildscript and that **gradle.properties** is its properties file. But **settings.gradle** really throws me. Inside it I see:

```
rootProject.name = "someApp"
```

But this seems like it belongs in `gradle.properties`. I'm also wondering where the `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` files come from, they seem to be generated.

Finally, I'm wondering why there are so many ***.gradle** files under the `gradle/` dir: are these plugins, or extension scripts of some sort. They are all pulled in from the main `build.gradle` like so:

```
apply "gradle/fizz.gradle"
apply "gradle/buzz.gradle"
etc.
```

So:

1. What properties are supposed to go in `settings.gradle` that are *not* supposed to go in `gradle.properties`?
2. How are the `gradlew`/`gradlew.bat` files generated?
3. Why would someone have so many disparate `*.gradle` files? Why not just 1 big `build.gradle` buildscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `gradle.properties` is normal properties file, while `settings.gradle` is also a build script. You can add there some code that will be executed during build. Typically this file is needed when You have a multi-module project.

2) When You type `gradle tasks` in project build directory (empty build.gradle is enough to see it) You'll see `wrapper` task. This task is used to generate scripts You're asking about. More [info](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

3) The reason is that all these files have different responsibilities that are cleanly separated.

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - so for #3 above do these multiple `*.gradle` files exist so that you can reuse different buildscripts across multiple projects?

Comment: build.gradle exists always, gradle.properties from time to time (when You need to alter JVM settings for instance), settings.gradle in multimodule projects not multiple projects. To reuse scripts among multiple projects You can implement a plugin.